# How to easily insert into objectify DB

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have an GAE Server with an objectify database.

I am looking for a way to insert many line into my database.
I tried to do a main like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();
ofy.put(new MyWhateverObject("1"));   
ofy.put(new MyWhateverObject("2"));   
ofy.put(new MyWhateverObject("3"));
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread.
```

How should I do it??

IMPORTANT: I don't want to test my application with LocalServiceTestHelper, I want to really insert lines into my DB.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this dev server or production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be running this code from within a `main` method.

In the case of unit testing (which seems to be what every other post I tried to reference seems to be about) you should be executing your code in the context of a class using `LocalServiceTestHelper`.

However, you specifically mentioned you are *not* interested in local testing, so you should be executing your code in the context of a servlet (see [Requests and Servlets](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Requests_and_Servlets), or [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction) for a good example).

Comment: So the only solution to easly insert lines into my objectify database is to send request to my server?? I thought there was a way to easily create lines. I am used to Oracle, and it's very easy to create line (insert into).

Comment: If you want to interact with the datastore outside of your App Engine app, you can use the Remote API (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi).

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. I made it with a very simple main:  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  RemoteApiOptions options = new RemoteApiOptions().server("localhost", 8888).credentials("whatever", "");
  RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
  installer.install(options);
  try {
  ObjectifyService.register(MyClass.class);
   Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();
   ofy.put(new MyClass());
  } finally {
   installer.uninstall();
  }
 }